# Output redirection using fork() and execl()

Tags: c++, linux

I want to use fork() to spawn off a new process in my program. The new process will have only one task: To redirect the mouse input to a serial port. I have tested the following command with success in a terminal window: **hexdump /dev/input/mice > /dev/ttyS0**

So far I have managed to use fork to create a child process, but my problem is that I can't seem to get my execl() method to work properly:

```
execl("/usr/bin/hexdump", "hexdump", "/dev/input/mice > /dev/ttyS0", (char*) NULL);
```

I have tried other variants also, like this:

```
execl("/usr/bin/hexdump", "hexdump", "/dev/input/mice", ">", "/dev/ttyS0", (char*) NULL);
```

But always with the same result, an exit value of 1 (general error).

It's also worth mentioning that I have managed to make it work by using the popen() method, where you can type the command exactly like you would have done in a terminal. The problem with popen() is that I have not found a good way for terminating the process.
With fork() I get the PID, and can terminate the process by using:

```
kill(pid, SIGKILL);
```

This is a requirement, as I have to be able to stop and restart the output redirection as desired while the program is running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot perform redirection in this way.

If you want to redirect `stdout` for a process you're about to `exec`, you need to `open` the path and `dup2` it onto the appropriate file descriptor.

Example:

```
 if (!(pid = fork()) 
 {
     int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_WRONLY);
     dup2(fd, 1);  // redirect stdout
     execl("/usr/bin/hexdump", "hexdump", "/dev/input/mice", NULL);
 }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much! Just a short question: Do I need to close the file descriptor before killing the process, or will it be closed automatically when the process is killed?

Comment: The file descriptors open to the child get closed when the child dies, just as with any process.  If you notice above, I open `/dev/ttyS0` in the body of the `if`, so that only the child has an open file descriptor for `/dev/ttyS0`.  So, when you kill the child, that fd closes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the ">" argument. This symbol is specific to the shell (bash or dash in your case). But `execl()` call does not invoke the shell and passes the arguments to the `hexdump`

As a possible solution I can propose using of `system()` call

Like `system("hexdump /dev/input/mice > /dev/ttyS0")`

This will simulate the behaviour of your command line experiment.

And to get the pid of your process you can continue doing `fork()`, just call the `system()` in place of `execl()`

Comment: This would probably also work, but isn't it safer to use exec()? As suggested e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830611/to-system-or-fork-exec)?

Comment: Of course not - exec() won't do the job because of ">" argument. You do need the shell for this. Or use dup2() as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you for pointing out the issue with ">" not working in an exec() call.