# How to execute an application2 from another application1 without freezing application1?

Tags: c++, c, macos

With the help of the function `int system (const char* command);` I can execute an application from another application. The `stdlib.h` contains the function `system`.
For example:

> click button1 in application1 -> open application2.

The Button1 clicked event executes the function

```
system(application2.app);
```

But when application2 is executed application1 freezes until application2 will be closed. Is it possible to execute application2 without blocking application1?

Comment: Start it as a separate process. You want a `fork()` maybe.

Comment: You might like to look for "*`fork()` followed by `exec*()`*" examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fork](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fork+2)

```
pid_t pid;

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    /* this is the new process, execute the other application here */
    system("your application file path");
    _exit(0);
 }
 /* Here you continue in application1
```

And I would recomment to take a look at the [execve](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?execve+2) and family functions, instead of `system`.

Comment: Using `system()` is highly incompatible, as one never knows which kind of shell is started. The preferred way is to use a member of the `exec*()`-family of functions. Also please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14830611/694576

Comment: @alk Yes, i recommended that.

Comment: You should update your answer.  You mention execve (the exec* family of functions is the correct way to go), but your answer, in code, still uses system()

Comment: This works fine and dandy on Linux, no love for Windows though (unless you're using Cygwin...)

Comment: There is a `osx` tag in the post.