# using system() function to play sound in the background

Tags: c++

i made a game in Ubuntu in which i use .wav files to play the sound in the background using this function:-

`system("canebrake-gtk-play -f file_path")`

But when the sound is played the whole game stops means the animation stops but after the completion of the sound , the game starts again normally....But this is creating a mess for me and showing a very bad impact , so i want to remove this creepy thing from my game ...so any help would be appreciable..
THANKX

Comment: Use a thread/subprocess to play the sound but this not a good way actually. Try to use some C++ framework to play the sound.

Answer (score 1):

*`system("canebrake-gtk-play -f file_path")`*

That's going to be executed synchronously from your code. That's why your program is blocked on execution of this.

You might consider to execute that using a `fork()` and `exec()`to be executed at background.

Providing a separate thread (instead of a process), is another option.

Comment: @MohsinMushtaq See here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830611/to-system-or-fork-exec.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way.

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
   system("canebrake-gtk-play -f file_path");
   exit(0);
}
```

You could also use a thread instead of another process.